# Firemonkey: How can I open native IOS maps from my app?

Tags: ios, dictionary, firemonkey

What I need to do is just open and send an string to IOS native map. The string contains the adress.

I found this code that work fine on android, but just doesn't work on IOS, why?

```
function OpenNavigation(const Q: string; const Coord: TLocationCoord2D): Boolean;
var
  CoordString: String;
begin
  //Open in Google Maps
  {$IFDEF ANDROID}
  exit(OpenURL('http://maps.google.com/?q=' + Q));
  {$ELSE}

  //In iOS, if Google Maps is installed, use it, otherwise, use Apple Maps
  //If we have coordinates, use them as the start address
  {$IFDEF IOS}
  exit(OpenURL('http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=' + Q));
  //Get a string of the longitute and latitute seperated by a comma if set
  if (Coord.Latitude <> 0.0) or (Coord.Longitude <> 0.0) then
  begin
    CoordString := Coord.Latitude.ToString + ',' + Coord.Longitude.ToString;
  end
  else begin
    CoordString := '';
  end;
  if not OpenURL('comgooglemaps://?daddr=' + Q) then
  begin
    if (0.0 < CoordString.Length) then
    begin
      exit(OpenURL('http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=' + Q + '&saddr=loc:' + CoordString));
    end
    else begin
      exit(OpenURL('http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=' + Q));
    end;
  end
  else begin
    exit(true);
  end;
  {$ELSE}
  //Unsupported platform
  exit(false);
  {$ENDIF IOS}
  {$ENDIF ANDROID}
end;
```

EDIT: The version that I'm using is RadStudio 10.1 Berlin

EDIT²: I changed twice the tag 'dictionary' to 'map' but change back to dictionary idk why.

Answer (score 1):

To open Maps App from another iOS App, you can do following :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/?address=yourAddressHere")!)
```

You can also get `CLLocation` location using [CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLGeocoder/geocodeAddressDictionary:completionHandler:)

Please also look into this [stack overflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787653/open-apple-maps-programmatically-in-ios8-xcode-7-swift-2) for further details.

Comment: Thanks dude, but this code doesn't work on Firemonkey, this is Swift i guess. Thanks anyway...

Comment: I have no experience in FireMonkey, but may be you can change the url to access maps, and use "http://maps.apple.com/?address=yourAddressHere"

Also have al look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877683/how-can-i-launch-the-navigation-app-on-ios-and-android-with-rad-studio-firemonke

Comment: Didn't worked. I don't know what to do anymore, I can't find an answer on the internet. That's discouraging...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

```
OpenURL('http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=YourAddress');
```